# Is there a way to make opacity work like a layer?

Tags: react-native

I have a certain style of a button, and I want to have a "disabled" state, for this I want to make the entire view of the button have an opacity of 0.2.

Here is my problem, the opacity of 0.2 affects the parent <View> & all of it's children, which makes the <Text> to have an opacity of 0.2 and blend with the View behind it.

I expected the entire View to behave like a layer in Photoshop or Figma, now I know that it's not the case and that this is how react native render works.
But I do think there must be a solution that might involve masking the parent View according to the child Text.

[opacity: 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny6uk.png)

[opacity: 0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6dtW.png)

I want something like this:
[Parent View is hidden when making the text transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpQBV.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy trick to this.

Create a `View` inside a `View` and give it `position absolute` with the opacity.

Here is how

```js
<View style={{width:100, height:30, overflow:"hidden"}}>
  <View style={{position:"absolute", width:"100%", height:"100%", backgroundColor:"red", opacity:0.2}} />
  <Text> some text</Text>
</View>
```

I wrote this on the fly, you will have to change some style to make it perfect